# How can i toggle two different native-base drawers in same screen or same class

Tags: react-native, native-base, drawer

**Issue Description**

I want to toggle two different native-base drawers on the same screen or the same class, how can we do it. if I use drawer inside another drawer, only the main drawer is toggled.

react-native version - 0.60.5, native-base version - ^2.13.8.

**Expected behaviour**

I want to toggle two different drawers on the same screen.

**Actual behaviour**

only the main drawer is toggled whether main drawer or the second drawer is toggled.
sample code which I tried is below there.

```
render() {
return (
  <ImageBackground
    source={require('@images/background.png')}
    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
    <Drawer
      side="right"
      openDrawerOffset={0.3}
      ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
      content={<SideMenu navigation={this.props.navigation} name={this.state.title} onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} />}
      onClose={() => this.closeDrawer} >
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Header
        title={"Header"}
        icon='menu'
        onPressMenu={this.onPressMenu}
      />
      <Drawer
        side="right"
        openDrawerOffset={0.3}
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SecondSideMenu navigation={this.props.navigation} name={this.state.title} onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected2} closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer} />}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer} >
        <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <View style={styles.iconView}>
            <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={() => this.onPressSubMenu()}
            >
              <Icon name={'menu'} size={width / 8.5} color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
             <ContactInformation navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        </Drawer>
    </View>
    </Drawer>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

}
}